# Embedded C: Able to access some struct members but not others

Tags: c, struct, boolean, avr

**The Problem**

On a personal project of mine, I have a struct defined in a UART abstraction library (let's call it UART.c and UART.h)I made for an AVR.

In UART.h:

```
typedef struct ST_UARTRX_MESSAGECONTENTS{
 uint8_t u_command[3];          //Command 
 uint32_t u32_value;            //Parameter for Command
 boolean b_newValue;    //Is there new value written here
 boolean b_Error;       //Is there an error with this message
} ST_UARTRX_MESSAGECONTENTS;

volatile ST_UARTRX_MESSAGECONTENTS st_uartRX_MessageContents;
```

So basically it's a structure that holds a UART message, it has a "b_newValue" that's a flag for when a new message is received. A message is "received" when the AVR receives a new line "\n".

In the header file of another file (let's call "foo.h"): I include my "UART abstraction library" and put this in the header:

```
extern volatile ST_UARTRX_MESSAGECONTENTS st_uartRX_MessageContents;
```

But then in foo.c, I try to access the "b_newValue":

```
if(st_uartRX_MessageContents.b_newValue){
    st_uartRX_MessageContents.b_newValue = TRUE;  
    fsm_state = ST_STOREMACRO;
}
```

But the "if" is never entered even if my debugger says the struct value is indeed true:

[image]

You can see I have breaked at the if statement. If I hit "Step", it just skips over it and doesn't enter!

Boolean typedef for reference:

```
typedef enum{FALSE, TRUE} boolean;
```

**Some things I've tried**

When I look at the compiled ASM code, I see that general purpose register R24 is used to load the b_newValue, but it loads 0x00, not 0x01 like I'd expect.

```
uartTX_sendArray(st_uartRX_MessageContents.u_command, sizeof st_uartRX_MessageContents.u_command);
delay_ms(2000);
if(st_uartRX_MessageContents.b_newValue){
    st_uartRX_MessageContents.b_newValue = TRUE;  
    fsm_state = ST_STOREMACRO;
}
```

I used my "UART: send this array" function to send the ascii "command" from the same structure, and it works! I have no idea why my foo.c can see the "command" but not the "b_newValue".

I've been ripping my hair out for hours. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Judging by the layout of the code you posted, `typedef struct ST_UARTRX_MESSAGECONTENTS{...` is located in the same file that defines `volatile ST_UARTRX_MESSAGECONTENTS st_uartRX_MessageContents;`, which is supposedly a `.c` file. But how did you manage to declare `extern volatile ST_UARTRX_MESSAGECONTENTS st_uartRX_MessageContents;` in the `.h` file then? Name `ST_UARTRX_MESSAGECONTENTS` is not supposed to be known in the `.h` file in such case. How does it work then? Can you provide a more precise information on how the declarations and definitions are spread across different source files?

Comment: What is the value of `fsm_state`? If it is always `ST_STOREMACRO` and since you are storing `TRUE` into `b_newValue` when it is already `TRUE` could it be possible that the compiler has optimised out that whole block as it's logically a noop?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that if such declaration layout *compiles*, then you might have *another* independent declaration of `ST_UARTRX_MESSAGECONTENTS` somewhere else with a different member sequence. Something like that can easily confuse the debugger and lead to the effect you observe.

Comment: Definitely something strange going on here when the `b_newValue` is loaded into a register in the ASM as opposed to always being read from the main memory, this shows you that the access to the struct member is not actually volatile. If all else fails you might be able to force a read like by doing something like this: `*(volatile boolean *) &st_uartRX_MessageContents.b_newValue` this is obviously horrendous though so use as a last  resort only.

Comment: @AnT Thanks for your input. The typedef is in the header file of the UART abstraction. The extern struct is in the foo.h, which includes the header of the UART abstraction library. I'll try to clarify this above.

Comment: @AlanAu the fsm_state is an enum of all the possible states the foo.c could be in. The code you see is in a "ST_MAIN" state. When a new UART message has been received, the software goes to the ST_STOREMACRO state.

Comment: @NickWilliams I meant, what is the exact value of `fsm_state` just before the `if` block?

Comment: @AlanAu It would be ST_MAIN, because that's the value it has to be to enter the ST_MAIN state.

Comment: It's late for me guys, I'll be sure to respond to anything that comes up tomorrow morning first thing. Thanks for everyone's help so far.

Comment: @shuttle87 it not being treated as volatile while a possibility, but it isn't guaranteed by the value being loaded into the register. If the register is reloaded before each use it's fine volatile behavior. If it were loaded once before the (assumed) loop began and not again, then that'd be a problem, or if it assumed a set wasn't necessary because it was already true.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by what you posted now, you have your struct object *defined* in the header file `UART.h`

```
volatile ST_UARTRX_MESSAGECONTENTS st_uartRX_MessageContents;
```

That's formally illegal (if you include `UART.h` into multiple translation units) and is generally not a good idea  even if some compilers accept it as an extension. I would suggest you move the above definition into a `UART.c` file and place a non-defining declaration

```
extern volatile ST_UARTRX_MESSAGECONTENTS st_uartRX_MessageContents;
```

into `UART.h`.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your time. I added the extern to the define in the header and put the definition at the top of UART.c. However I still can't enter the "if" even though "b_newValue" is certainly set to TRUE.